# React Popper with ClickAwayListener triggers onClick of all child components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

the Popper with the ClickAwayListener included, triggers all onClick functions of child components. What would be the correct way of preventing this? If you need more information please let me know!

**Parent Code:**

```
<Popper
                    open={Boolean(this.state.openNotification)}
                    anchorEl={this.state.openNotification}
                    placement='bottom-end'
                    disablePortal={true}
                    transition
                >
                    {({TransitionProps, placement}) => (
                        <Grow {...TransitionProps} id="notification-menu-list-grow">
                            <Paper className={classes.notificationsPaper}>

                                <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={this.handleCloseNotification.bind(this)}>
                                    {this.state.notificationList.length > 0 ?
                                        <List>
                                            {
                                                this.state.notificationList.map((notification, index) =>
                                                    <NotificationListItem key={index} id={notification._id}
                                                                          type={notification.type}
                                                                          title={notification.title}
                                                                          read={notification.read}
                                                                          timestamp={notification.timestamp}/>)
                                            }
                                        </List>
                                    :
                                        <Typography className={classes.noNotifText}>Keine Benachrichtigungen</Typography>
                                    }
                                </ClickAwayListener>

                                <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete all" className={classes.deleteAllIConButton} onClick={this.deleteAllNotifications()}>
                                    <ClearAllIcon/>
                                </IconButton>
                            </Paper>
                        </Grow>
                    )}
                </Popper>
```

**Child Component:**

```
return (
        <ListItem id={props.id}>
            <ListItemText className={!props.read ? classes.notificationHeaderTitleUnread : classes.notificationHeaderTitle}
                          primary={props.title} secondary={props.timestamp}/>
            <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete" onClick={deleteNotification()}>
                    <DeleteOutlineIcon/>
                </IconButton>
            </ListItemSecondaryAction>
        </ListItem>
    );
```

Comment: Shouldn't your onClick be like `onClick={() => deleteNotification()}`?

Comment: Works with that, whats the difference between those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my comment solved the problem, hence, I'll post it as an answer.

Kindly change your onClick to `onClick={() => deleteNotification()}`.

- `onClick={() => deleteNotification()}` is function declaration i.e. you have passed a function.
- By writing `onClick={deleteNotification()}`, you are calling the deleteNotification function, not passing it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome. Kindly mark this as answer.